Change the location of pubsub cloud function
I have a pubsub cloud function but it is deploying to us-central1 by default. I need it in Europe. How can I change the location of it? I know we can set the location of onRequest functions like this
onRequest(
  { timeoutSeconds: 15, region: ["europe-west2"], maxInstances: 5 },
  async (request, response) => {}
)

. How do I do this with the onMessagePublished function?

You can achieve a similar result like this:
onMessagePublished(
  { topic: "random", region: "europe-west2" },
  async (event) => {}
)


Options parameter documentation: PubSubOptions which extends EventHandlerOptions which extends GlobalOptions.

Thank you! I couldn't find this documentation on Google. This is amazing and very helpful!
